# Create custom package from nginx source - renaming nginx to custom-nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, packages, dpkg, compilation

My dist is Ubuntu 14.04

**use case**

I am attempting to create my own packaged nginx called 'custom-nginx'. It needs to install itself into alternative directories as so it does not interfere with the normal operation of nginx. 'custom-nginx' will listen on a different port number and will serve API requests.

**some commands i'm using for preparation**

```
apt-get install dpkg-dev
wget -O - http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get source nginx
apt-get build-dep nginx
```

we now have a directory `nginx-1.9.5` which contains everything we need to compile nginx.

inside `nginx-1.9.5` / `debian` there is a `control` file, open that up and I can see where to change the package name on line 9

```
Package: nginx
```

to

```
Package: custom-nginx
```

Taking one step at a time, I attempt to compile this, without changing anything else and the compile fails near the end when it complains some directories don't exist. These directories are the ones listed at the end of the `rules` file in the section named *override_dh_auto_install:*

```
dpkg-buildpackage

...

/usr/bin/install -m 644 debian/nginx.conf debian/nginx/etc/nginx/
/usr/bin/install: target ‘debian/nginx/etc/nginx/’ is not a directory: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/custom-nginx/nginx-1.9.5'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Can someone please shed some light on this for me. At this stage (without focusing too much on the designated paths for executables etc) I just want to compile it using a custom name.

Thanks